# Pandas comparing dataframe with series containing datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to compare a Dataframe with a Series to check if one of the rows in the df is equal to the series, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

d = pd.DataFrame([[1, dt.datetime(1990,12,10)],
                  [2, dt.datetime(1990,12,11)]])
s = d.loc[0].copy()

print(d == s)  # or d.gt(s) which should do the same
```

This breaks with the following error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comparing the `values` yields the expected results:

```
d.values == s.values
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Also this error isn't raised using strings:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[1, "a"], [2, "b"]])

s = d.loc[1].copy()

print(s == d)
#       0      1
#0   True   True
#1  False  False
```

Is this a bug in pandas or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I'm using python 3.6 with pandas 0.20.3

I opened an issue on pandas github:
[17411](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17411)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had version 0.20.3 which is the latest available version through pip or conda.

[Version 0.21](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), which is the last dev version on github seems to have solved the issue.

I'll delete the question as soon as version 0.21 is on pypi

Answer (score 1):

## Recant

as mentioned in the comments, (and probably worth adding to the question) this works for strings, so i don't see why it should not work for `datetimes`

discussion on github [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7830%20and%20https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13129) suggests that it is an ongoing debate regarding whether a datetime should be false when compared to a number or not.

---

if you print `d` and `s` you get the following:

d:

```
   0          1
0  1 1990-12-10
1  2 1990-12-11
```

s:

```
0                      1
1    1990-12-10 00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

in s, the numbers 0,1 on the left there are the index (which is the key by which `s == d` compares) so your code is comparing `1` to `1` and then `2` against `1990-12-10 00:00:00` - which is why you get your error.

---

as to why this works with values - `.values` gives back the numpy array without the indexes, so the comparison is done on the shape you were expecting rather than considering the indexes.

Comment: If what you say is true, the following should also break: `d = pd.DataFrame([[1, "a"],
                  [2, "b"]])
s = d.loc[0].copy()`, `d == s`, but it doesn't

Comment: @gionni that is really interesting - I'm going to look into it more.

Comment: I really appreciate it, thanks. I'm trying to run the example in debug to understand how it works, it is quite complicated

Comment: I can't find a related issue on the github - it might be worth posting this there. there are a few issues regarding mixed type comparison eg https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7830 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13129

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it just now

Comment: @gionni link it in your question when you do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're comparing two objects which don't support comparison.

I'd try something like this:

`d[d[1] == dt.datetime(1990,12,10)]`

Comment: I don't know which columns have dates in them and which ones don't plus to check all columns I would have to put it in a for cycle